# Can't unpack tuples when tuple of tuples has single tuple. Why? Works with array of tuples

Tags: python, tuples, iterable-unpacking

Why can't a single tuple in an *tuple* of tuples be unpacked? A single tuple in any *array* of tuples does work, however.

**Tuple of Tuples (many tups)** --- Works

```py
mytup=(([1,2,3],['a','b','c'],99),([2,2,3],['b','b','c'],100))
for t in mytup:
    z1,z2,z3=t
    print(z3)
```

Result:

```py
99
100
```

**Tuple of Tuples (single tup)** --- Does not work

```py
mytup=(([1,2,3],['a','b','c'],99))
for t in mytup:
    z1,z2,z3=t
    print(z3)
```

Result:

```py
3
c
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-171-1c4755f1cb92> in <module>
     13 mytup=(([1,2,3],['a','b','c'],99)) #,([2,2,3],['b','b','c'],100))
     14 for t in mytup:
---> 15     z1,z2,z3=t
     16     print(z3)

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

**Array of Tuples** --- Works

```py
mytup=[([1,2,3],['a','b','c'],99)]
for t in mytup:
    z1,z2,z3=t
    print(z3)
```

Result:

```py
99
```

Comment: `(([1,2,3],['a','b','c'],99))` should be `(([1,2,3],['a','b','c'],99),)` the outer parentheses aren't treated as tuple are instead treated as parentheses that signify order

Comment: Ah, forgot about that. So it does work with a tuple of tuples. I just defined my single tuple wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just place a comma before the last closing bracket to show it's a tuple:

```py
mytup = (([1,2,3],['a','b','c'],99),)
```

Comment: So it does work with a tuple of tuples. I just defined my single tuple wrong.